# Can I play Google Doodle Fruit Games today?

Tags: google-doodles

In celebration of the 2016 Rio Olympics, Google launched a Doodle consisting of a series of games themed on antropomorphic fruits playing sports. Eventually, like all Doodles, it stopped.

It's easy to find references to them today, but none are playable.

Is there a way to play these games today? Preferably on mobile, but desktop would do.

https://www.google.com/doodles/fruitgames

https://www.google.com/doodles/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-1

Comment: I don't remember any of the doodles being playable.  Perhaps try the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160401000000*/http://google.com) for google on the days of the Olympics (August 5, 2016 to August 21, 2016).

Comment: @Timmy Jim good Idea, seemed promising, but no. I see the Doodle, but, when I click on it, "Page cannot be displayed due to robots.txt.".

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Google has an archive of all of their doodles you can find it here https://www.google.com/doodles
They should be playable. And most of them do require you to use a desktop

Comment: I found quite a few of them, but couldn't play. https://www.google.com/doodles/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-8

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. It normal works for me

Comment: Weirs, I tried on Chrome and everything. So you actually can play it today? Any special configurations? I'll try from another machine.

Answer (score -1):

These were only in the Google app so maybe you could find an APK of around that time and set your to time to that time too

Answer (score -2):

To answer the question, no you can't play those games today.